# Explicitly need to reload the system wide PATH . /etc/profile everytime for JAVAC to work in Ubuntu12.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, javac

I have installed JAVA 1.8.0_05 using the following tutorial;

`http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux`

After configuring my path in `. /etc/profile` as shown below I rebooted my Ubuntu

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin

JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_05/jre

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin

export JAVA_HOME

export JRE_HOME

export PATH
```

Everything works fine up to the point where I give `java -version` but `JAVAC -VERSION` is not recognized. Now when I reload the system PATH using `. /etc/profile`, it works ( I mean JAVAC -version works).

Can you please help me and fix this problem permanently? So that I don't have to reload the system path again and again..

(Note: Without loading the system path every time, my JAVA -version works fine)

Comment: for /etc/profile to load automatically try to logout and login again. If you changed the path info in the current login session it wont be populated automatically. Also linux is case sensitive so -version is not same as -VERSION

Comment: You can try adding `export PATH` to your `.bashrc` or the similar file for your preferred shell.

Comment: Those are not great directions. I personally prefer the [webupd8 method](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html). It would allows you to use `update-java-alternatives`, and is the way documented in the [help center](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java).

Comment: Thanks Nazgul but i have already tried logout and login..but still it doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I am actually using Zshell,,,so do i have to Export path .zshrc..If yes could you please tell me ho to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From document https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Run this command from terminal

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```